# How to get Array data from Object inside in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

In, my Project I'm using `Vue.js` and `Laravel`. I've a dynamic field form which is validate by `Laravel` end. but when I get the validation message via `axios` i can't separate it from the response.

Here, is my Laravel code.

```
      $this->validate($request,[
            'requested_by' => 'required',
            'requested_date' => 'required',
            'issued_by' => 'required',
            'supplier' => 'required',
            'data.*.product' => 'required',
            'data.*.quantity' => 'required',
            'data.*.unit' => 'required',
            'data.*.unit_price' => 'required',
        ]);
```

Vue code for `axios` request -

```
  axios.post('/api/requisition',{
              'data' : this.inputs,
              'requested_by': this.form.request_by,
              'requested_date': this.form.request_date,
              'issued_by': this.form.issue_by,
              'supplier': this.form.supplier,})
          .then(response => {
              console.log(response)
          })
          .catch(err => {
              this.allerrors =  err.response.data.errors
              console.log(this.allerrors)

          })
```

In my response I get the image like output:

[image]

> How can i destruct it from this format for every dynamic form index, is there any solutions to do something.

Comment: this.inputs what contains?

Comment: this.inputs contains all dynamics fields in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve my problem this way.

```
axios.post('/api/requisition',{
              'data' : this.inputs,
              'requested_by': this.form.request_by,
              'requested_date': this.form.request_date,
              'issued_by': this.form.issue_by,
              'supplier': this.form.supplier,})
          .then(response => {
              console.log(response)
          })
          .catch(err => {
              this.allerrors =  err.response.data.errors
              console.log(this.allerrors["data.[0].product"])
          })
```

In dynamic form view handle this way -

```
 <div :class="['form-group',allerrors['data.'+key+'.product'] ? 'has-error error' : '']">
       <label for="">Product<i class="text text-danger">*</i></label>
         <select class="form-control" v-model="input.product" @change="getData($event,k)">
            <option value="" disabled selected>-Select Product-</option>

       </select>

     </div>

 <span v-if="allerrors['data.'+key+'.product']" :class="['text text-danger']">{{allerrors["data."+key+".product"]}}</span>  

 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I really like the lodash answer to be honest. But since this was fun to do. Here is an example without lodash.

```js
const res = {
  "data.0.name": "Bob",
  "data.0.gender": "Male",
  "data.0.age": 27,
  "data.1.name": "Kelly",
  "data.1.gender": "Female",
  "data.1.age": 24,
  "issuedBy: "Morty",
  "requestedBy": "Rick"
};

const output = [];

Object.keys(res)
  .filter(key => /data/.test(key))
  .forEach(key => {
    const [index, prop] = key.replace('data.', '').split('.');
    if (!output[index]) {
      output[index] = {};
    }
    output[index][prop] = res[key]
  });

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's kind of gross but you can reflect on the object to get the keys and restructure it however you like, there are more than one way to do it but something like:

```
import _ from "lodash"

function transformData(data) {
  return Object.entries(data).reduce((obj, [k,v]) => _.set(obj, k, v), {})
}
```